Exclude a namespace from Obfuscation with Eazfuscator
I have a DotNetBrowser license in my project, and it is bound to my namespace. However, Eazfuscator is obfuscating the namespace.
I tried to prevent this by adding the following lines(one at a time) to AssemblyInfo.cs:
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "namespace(MyNamespace)", Exclude = true)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Exclude = true, Feature = "namespace('MyNamespace'):-rename")]

I also tried with Exclude = false, but my namespace still gets obfuscated.
Can anyone tell me how to prevent my namespace from being obfuscated?

According to the document of eazfuscator, it removes the namespaces of renamed types, but you can add the namespaces back by
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "type renaming pattern 'MyNamespace'.*", Exclude = false)]

or
[Obfuscation(Feature = "type renaming pattern 'MyNamespace'.*", Exclude = false)]
class MyClass


Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I used your first suggestion and put it into the AssemblyInfo.cs
